# Python -> Read file and create 3 lists with 3 strings like markers to divide file

Tags: python, string, list, strip, divide

this is my first meeting with Python :)
I have question -> my code and question bellow:

I am trying to divide input file to 3 files (Program info/Program core/Toollist)

- I can match and write first part like i wanted (break on loop when find string in line),

how can i tell I want to "continue with looping from this found string" and write to second list/file
or how can I mark all lines between two strings to append it in list and write do file after.
Thanks a lot guy. I wish you merry christmas and will be happy from your help

```
import os

filename = "D327971_fc1.i"                  # current program name
file = open(filename, 'r')                  # read current program

if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:          # check if size of file is null
    print('File is empty')
    file.close()
else:
    read = file.readlines()
    programdef = []
    toollist = []
    core = []
   
    line_num = -1
    for line in read:
    
        start_line_point = "Zacatek" in line
        end_line_point = "Konec" in line
        toollist_point = "nastroj" in line
  
        programdef.append(line.strip())
        if start_line_point: break
        core.append(line.strip())           
        if end_line_point: 
        toollist.append(line.strip())  
        
    with open('0progdef.txt', 'w') as f:
       f.write(str(programdef)) 
    with open('1core.txt', 'w') as f:
       f.write(str(core))
    with open('2toollist.txt', 'w') as f:
       f.write(str(toollist))
```

Divide input file to 3 lists with marking lines by find string and esport this lists to 3 files after it.

Comment: Your goal seems pretty unclear to me: could you specify exactly how you know which lines go into which category, preferably with an example ?

Comment: I can find and write strings in file start_line_point , end_line_point and toollist_point. I can write programdef list from start of file to first point (start_line_point) but when i try write somethink between start_line_point and end_line_point it write only one line with match of string and not continuing with loop through all lines till i stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to split the file into 3 different files: the first one includes all lines before "Zacatek", the second one includes all lines between "Zacatek" and "Konec" and the third one includes all line between "Konec" and "nastroj".

You could change your `for` loop to something like:

```
keywords = {0:'Zacatek', 1:'Konec', 2:'nastroj'}
index = 0

for line in read:
    if index == 3:
        break
    if keywords[index] in line:
        index += 1
        continue
    if index == 0:
        programdef.append(line.strip())
    elif index == 1:
        core.append(line.strip())
    elif index == 2 : 
        toollist.append(line.strip())
```

This will create the three expected files containing `lists` of the lines in the original file.

Comment: I think you understood the general purpose (better than I anyway :) ); I'm not sure the keywords are correctly placed, but it should be easy to adjust after OP comments.

Comment: thanks for this hint. it works well. i will make some edits, but it helps a lot,